# Let $W$ be a subspace of a vector space $V$, then which of the following are correct

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

[image]

I think $W=0$. But I have not been able to prove mathematically.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is right. Every subspace contains $0$. Suppose $W$ contains some nonzero vector $e_1$. Extend this vector to a basis $\{e_1,e_2,...,e_n\}$ an define $f(\sum a_ie_i)=a_1$. This gives an element $f$ of $V^{*}$ and $f(e)=1$ contradicting the hypothesis.  Hence $W=\{0\}$.

Comment: What happens when $\dim V = \infty$?

Comment: The argument works even in infinite dimensional case provided $V^{*}$ stands for all linear functionals on $V$. Since OP didn't talk about any topology I assume that there is no continuity requirement on $f$. @RobertLewis